# How old is superuser.com?

Tags: discussion

I just went to superuser.com and noticed that the yearling badge (  Active member for a year, earning at least 200 reputation. This badge can be awarded multiple times.
) hasn't been awarded to anyone yet. I find this hard to believe... is SuperUser.com less than a year old or something?

Comment: Can't wait for it's first birthday! I'm going to make a SU cake!

Answer (score 7):

It was opened on [July 14, 2009](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/super-user-semi-private-beta-begins/).

Answer (score 1):

You may check [this guy](https://superuser.com/users/-1) age - 2009/07/12

Comment: funny, why does that guy have over 12K in votes cast?

Comment: @akf: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/community-user

Comment: @akf, please check jeff answer [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44960/why-does-community-user-have-45380-upvotes-on-meta-and-only-458-on-so), one big reason is because of lots of questions from SO migrated to SU, and users didn't create account there.

Comment: @akf - When someone requests their account be deleted all their content and voting record are assigned to the community user so the voting record is consistent.  One very active and prominent superuser left in the last few months, and others have left prior to that as well.